# Poisson approximation to the Binomial distribution - verify solution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Harvard Law School courses often have assigned seating to facilitate
>   the “Socratic method.” Suppose that there are 100 first year Harvard
>   Law students, and each takes two courses: Torts and Contracts.
>   Both
>   are held in the same lecture hall (which has 100 seats), and the
>   seating is uniformly random and independent for the two courses.
>   Find a simple but accurate approximation to the probability that no one
>   has the same seat for both courses.

given solution:

Define $I_i$ to be the indicator for student $i$ having the same seat in both courses,so that $N=\sum_{i=1}^{100}I_i$ , Then $P(I_i = 1) = 1/100$, and the $I_i$ are weakly dependent. 
So $N$ is close to $Pois(\lambda)$ in distribution, where $\lambda = E(N) = 100E[I_1] = 1$. Thus $P(N = 0) \approx \frac{e^{-1}1^0}{0!} = e^{-1}=0.36787944117
$

my solution:

Define $I_i$ to be the indicator for student $i$ *not* having the same seat in both courses,so that $N=\sum_{i=1}^{100}I_i$ , Then $P(I_i = 1) = 99/100$, and the $I_i$ are weakly dependent. 
So $N$ is close to $Pois(\lambda)$ in distribution, where $\lambda = E(N) = 100E[I_1] = 99$. 
Thus 
$P(N = 100) \approx \frac{e^{-99} 99^{100}}{100!} = 0.03966085721 \neq e^{-1}$

Comment: The Poisson approximation to the Binomial distribution is only valid when $p$ is very small because from $\lambda=np$ we have $p=\frac{\lambda}n$ and we need $n$ to be large. See also [here](https://medium.com/@andrew.chamberlain/deriving-the-poisson-distribution-from-the-binomial-distribution-840cc1668239)

Comment: that was helpful, thanks!